# Points on a Cube

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

So I imagined this problem back in 2017 or 2018.

Let $n>k\ge 0$ be integers.

Take a $n$-hypercube with side $1$.

Now on each "face" of $k$ dimensions, conviniently place a point.

Find $m$, where $m$ is the least dimension the convex hull of all the points can have.
Find $V$, where $V$ is the least $m$-volume a convex hull of $m$ dimensions of all the points can have.

So far I have found:

$n=1, k=0 \implies m=1, V=1$

$n=2, k=0 \implies m=2, V=1$

$n=2, k=1 \implies  m=1, V=\sqrt{2}$

$n=3, k=0 \implies m=3, V=1$

$n=3, k=1 \implies m=3, V=1/3$

$n=3, k=2 \implies m=1, V=\sqrt{3}$

$k=0 \implies m=n, V=1$

$k=n-1 \implies m=1, V=\sqrt{n}$

Does anyone know how to find more values of this?

Comment: $n=3, \;k=2 \; -> \;  m=1$ : points on faces K=2 may be coincident on an edge / vertex ?

Comment: You basically take opposing corners

Comment: How is V=1/3  for the n=3,k=1 case. I am getting 5/6 with every point on the mid point of a side

Comment: You push every point to the corner such that you make a regular tetrahedron with four corners. If you draw it, you'll see that the final tetrahedron is equal to the cube minus four tetrahedra. Each of those tetrahedra has volume 1*1*1/2*1/3=6
So the 4 tetrahedra together have a volume of 2/3, so the central tetrahedron has 1/3